# AngularJS share app core with multiple projects with Gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, gulp, shared

I'm currently developing an app with angularjs and cordova. I use Gulp to compile all the js, less, etc and merge it into a www folder. It's a big project and many apps will be created based on the same base core. I don't want to "clone" the entire project each time a have a new client because if a bug is found or a feature has to change I will have to redo everything in every single project.

I want to know if there's a way to create a build system with Gulp, where I could have a base core js/less, and that base js/less core could be replaced if the same js (or angular module name for instance) is found on another folder.

**Example image:**
[folder structure](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxV64FlNCp6eX01wbEhVbWc1NVU/view?usp=sharing)

In the above example, I will need a specific task to build "ProjectA".
I was thinking in something like "gulp build ProjectA" and then all files in "AppCore" folder would be compile only if there wasn't the same js, less or angular module inside "ProjectA" folder.

Or I don't know if is possible also to compile everything in "AppCore" and then override that result with the content found in "ProjectA" if equal. If something new in "ProjectA" that would be added.

Is there any gulp plugin to achieve this? Or does this have to be done in a different way?

What is the best way to create a flexible project like this with a shared based code core?

Thank you